# Web Scraping Rap lyrics on Rap Genius w/ Python

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, html-parsing, nltk

I am somewhat of a coding novice, and I have been trying to scrape Andre 3000's lyrics off Rap genius, http://genius.com/artists/Andre-3000, by using Beautiful Soup (A Python library for pulling data out of HTML and XML files). My end goal is to have the data in a string format. Here is what I have so far:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib2 import urlopen

artist_url = "http://rapgenius.com/artists/Andre-3000"

def get_song_links(url):
    html = urlopen(url).read()
    # print html 
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")
    container = soup.find("div", "container")
    song_links = [BASE_URL + dd.a["href"] for dd in container.findAll("dd")]

    print song_links

get_song_links(artist_url)
for link in soup.find_all('a'):
    print(link.get('href'))
```

So I need help with the rest of the code. How do I get his lyrics into string format? and then  how do I use the Natural Language Toolkit (NLTK) to token the sentences and words.

Comment: this is an awesome idea.  You're going to generate new lyrics right?  I'm thinking of doing the same for Tupac.  There must be a tool out there to generate their voices based on their existing songs.  I mean, if it's at word-level then all the new generated lyrics contain words that have been sung before by the artist so it would  be a matter of sampling and distorting the sound waves to get the generated voice to sound the way you want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's an example, how to grab all of the song links on the page, follow them and get the song lyrics:

```
from urlparse import urljoin
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests


BASE_URL = "http://genius.com"
artist_url = "http://genius.com/artists/Andre-3000/"

response = requests.get(artist_url, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.153 Safari/537.36'})

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "lxml")
for song_link in soup.select('ul.song_list > li > a'):
    link = urljoin(BASE_URL, song_link['href'])
    response = requests.get(link)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text)
    lyrics = soup.find('div', class_='lyrics').text.strip()

    # tokenize `lyrics` with nltk
```

Note that [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) module is used here. Also note that `User-Agent` header is required since the site returns `403 - Forbidden` without it.

Comment: this is great, however i get this error when i try to run it    "ImportError: No module named bs4"

Comment: @Ibrewster you need to install `beautifulsoup4`: run `pip install beautifulsoup4`.

Comment: yeah, i already had bs4 installed, and it wasnt working. so I tried reinstalling it and it still doesn't work.

Comment: Because you are using Python 3. In that case use pip3 install beautifulsoup4

Comment: I copy pasted this into a jupyter cell and when I run it, nothing seems to happen.

Answer (score 2):

First, for each link you will need to download that page and parse it with BeautifulSoup. Then look for a distinguishing attribute on that page that separates lyrics from other page content. I found <a data-editorial-state="accepted" data-classification="accepted" data-group="0"> to be helpful. Then run a .find_all on the lyrics page content to get all lyric lines. For each line you can call .get_text() to get the text from each lyrics line.

As for NLTK, once it is installed you can import it and parse sentences like so:

```
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize, sent_tokenize
words = [word_tokenize(t) for t in sent_tokenize(lyric_text)]
```

This will give you a list of all words in each sentence.

Answer (score 2):

Even if you can scrape the site, doesn't mean that you should, instead you can use the API from genius , just create the access token from the [Genius API site](https://genius.com/api-clients)

```
import lyricsgenius as genius #calling the API
api=genius.Genius('youraccesstokenhere12345678901234567890isreallylongiknow')
artist=api.search_artist('The artist name here')
aux=artist.save_lyrics(format='json', filename='artist.txt',overwrite=True, skip_duplicates=True,verbose=True)#you can change parameters acording to your needs,i dont recommend using this file directly because it saves a lot of data that you might not need and will take more time to clean it

titles=[song['title'] for song in aux['songs']]#in this case for example i just want title and lyrics
lyrics=[song['lyrics'] for song in aux['songs']]
thingstosave=[]
for i in range(0,128):
    thingstosave.append(titles[i])
    thingstosave.append(lyrics[i])
with open("C:/whateverfolder/alllyrics.txt","w") as output:
    output.write(str(thingstosave))
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this is still relevant! I'm doing the same thing with Eminem's lyrics, but from lyrics.com. Does it have to be from Rap Genius? I found lyrics.com to be easier to scrape.

To get Andre 3000's just change the code accordingly.

Here's my code; it gets song links and then scrapes those pages to get lyrics and appends the lyrics to a list:

```
import re
import requests
import nltk
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'http://www.lyrics.com/eminem'
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content)
gdata = soup.find_all('div',{'class':'row'})

eminemLyrics = []

for item in gdata:
    title = item.find_all('a',{'itemprop':'name'})[0].text
    lyricsdotcom = 'http://www.lyrics.com'
    for link in item('a'):
        try:
            lyriclink = lyricsdotcom+link.get('href')
            req = requests.get(lyriclink)
            lyricsoup = BeautifulSoup(req.content)
            lyricdata = lyricsoup.find_all('div',{'id':re.compile('lyric_space|lyrics')})[0].text
            eminemLyrics.append([title,lyricdata])
            print title
            print lyricdata
            print
        except:
            pass
```

This will give you the lyrics in a list. To print all titles:

```
titles = [i[0] for i in eminemLyrics]
print titles
```

To get a specific song:

```
titles.index('Cleaning out My Closet')
120
```

To tokenize the song, plug that value (`120`) in:

```
song = nltk.word_tokenize(eminemLyrics[120][1])
nltk.pos_tag(song)
```

Answer (score 0):

[GitHub / jashanj0tsingh / LyricsScraper.py](https://github.com/jashanj0tsingh/PythonTutorials) provides basic scraping of lyrics off genius.com into a text file where each row represents a song. It takes the artist's name as an input. The generated text file then can be easily fed to your custom `nltk` or the general parser to do stuff you want.

The code is below:

```
# A simple script to scrape lyrics from the genius.com based on atrtist name.

import re
import requests
import time
import codecs

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver

mybrowser = webdriver.Chrome("path\to\chromedriver\binary") # Browser and path to Web driver you wish to automate your tests cases.

user_input = input("Enter Artist Name = ").replace(" ","+") # User_Input = Artist Name
base_url = "https://genius.com/search?q="+user_input # Append User_Input to search query
mybrowser.get(base_url) # Open in browser

t_sec = time.time() + 60*20 # seconds*minutes
while(time.time()<t_sec): # Reach the bottom of the page as per time for now TODO: Better condition to check end of page.
    mybrowser.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
    html = mybrowser.page_source
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
    time.sleep(5)

pattern = re.compile("[\S]+-lyrics$") # Filter http links that end with "lyrics".
pattern2 = re.compile("\[(.*?)\]") # Remove unnecessary text from the lyrics such as [Intro], [Chorus] etc..

with codecs.open('lyrics.txt','a','utf-8-sig') as myfile:
    for link in soup.find_all('a',href=True):
            if pattern.match(link['href']):
                f = requests.get(link['href'])
                lyricsoup = BeautifulSoup(f.content,"html.parser")
                #lyrics = lyricsoup.find("lyrics").get_text().replace("\n","") # Each song in one line.
                lyrics = lyricsoup.find("lyrics").get_text() # Line by Line
                lyrics = re.sub(pattern2, "", lyrics)
                myfile.write(lyrics+"\n")
mybrowser.close()
myfile.close()
```

Comment: [Try adding some context to your answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers)

Comment: This just hangs on the artist's page.